# How to use dot net string.Split in Maxscript

Tags: .net, 3dsmax

How can I use the Split method from dot net in maxscript?
I've searched if there is such function in maxscript but I didnt found any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have two good news for you

> I've searched if there is such function in maxscript but I didnt found any

You can use *maxscript* native FilterString function like so:

```
mystring = "my_string_literate"
FilterString mystring "_"
```

> How can I use the Split method from dot net in maxscript?

```
mystring = DotNetObject "System.String" "my_string_literate"
mystring.split "_"
```

Both methods will return native *maxscript* array :

```
#("my", "string", "literate")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer